# Python writing floats into csv

Tags: python, csv

I am writing some data into a csv with Python. I have two values, `downloadSpeed` and `uploadSpeed`. When the value of the data is < 1 it is written into the csv file properly (*0.58795654* becames *0.58795654*). However, when the data is >1, float value is converted into an integer (*2.58795654* becames *258795654*). This is my code:

```py
with open(data_file_path, 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
 file = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
 file.writerow([date,downloadSpeed, uploadSpeed])
```

One solution I have come up with is converting the float to String, and then writing the string replacing the '.' for ','. However, after some reading, I don´t know why was this happening.

Solution:

```
file.writerow([date, str(downloadSpeed).replace(".",","), str(uploadSpeed).replace(".",",")])
```

**Edit:**

The problem is that Excel accepts both `,` and `.` as separators for floats < 1 but only accepts `,` as separator for floats > 1. That is why I was getting the error.

Comment: Can you give an example of `data is <1 it is written into the csv file properly.`

Comment: @quamrana 0.2261624210544649 is written properly in csv.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem "_when the data is >1, float value is converted into an integer_". Are you opening the CSV file in Excel?

Comment: @GinoMempin that was the problem: Excel. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working

```
import csv
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now()
downloadSpeed = 2.58795654
uploadSpeed = 0.2261624210544645

with open("test.csv", "a+", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow([date,downloadSpeed, uploadSpeed])
```

Output is:
2018-05-02 15:58:38.294086;2.58795654;0.2261624210544645

Are you altering the numbers in some way before writing?

Comment: The problem with that code, which works, is that data is been inserted in the same column, and I want it on different columns. That is why I used the ';' separator instead of the ','.

Comment: @PabloMartínez I've edited the answer, it should now format to what you want

Comment: Maybe its my Excel version, but that code does not work on my computer. It is still replacing the 2.58795654 float into 258795654. Thanks though.

Comment: open the csv file as a text file and check the output

Comment: @PabloMartínez please accept the answer if this solves your problem

Comment: Yes, you are right, the text file shows the data correctly. The problem is that Excel ignores the '.' unless it is something like '0,XXX'. The right way to work with .csv files is to use ',' instead of '.' for separating the integer and fractional part from a number. (At least with the European version of Excel).

Comment: Excel behaves very strangely with CSV files, I would suggest you just use your text editor for numerical CSV files.